# Linked list without dynamic allocation

Tags: arrays, c, function, linked-list, static

I have some problem about add and delete node in linked list without malloc. I delete node then add node again and print list but nothing happen. T try to check add_node function and it work normally but I can not check with del_node. Here is my code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_NODES        20

typedef struct node
{
    uint8_t value;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

static node node_arr[MAX_NODES] = {[0 ... 19] = 0};
static uint8_t next_node = 0;

void Add_Node(node **head, uint8_t val, uint8_t index)
{
    node *new_node = &(node_arr[index]);  
    next_node++;
    new_node->value = val;
    new_node->next = *head;    /* New node will point the current head*/
    *head = new_node;    /* Make new node become head of the list */
}

void Del_Node(node **head, uint8_t index)
{
    uint8_t run = 0;    /* Use run for reaching position */
    node *temp = *head;
    while((temp->next!= NULL) && (run != index)){
        temp = temp->next;
        run++;
    }
    temp = temp->next;   /* Let current node become next node */
    next_node --;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    Add_Node(&head, 2, 1);
    Add_Node(&head, 3, 2);
    Add_Node(&head, 4, 3);
    Add_Node(&head, 5, 4);
    Del_Node(&head, 3); // position 3 mean value 3 of list
    for (node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
          printf(" %d ", temp->value);
    }
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: `temp = temp->next; /* Let current node become next node */`. That doesn't do anything as it just sets a local variable. You need to change the previous node's next pointer to point to `temp->next`.

Comment: `next_node` isn't being used for anything. It's just being incremented and decremented. To properly use the array, you need to keep a **free list**. Initially the free list contains all of the nodes of the `node_arr`. The `Add_Node` function should remove the first node from the free list, and add it to the working list. The `Del_Node` function should remove the node from the working list, and add it to the free list.

Comment: @user3386109 next_node here I use for another purpose.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @kaylum I sure I'm wrong (with my program) but I wonder that I used double pointer (pass by reference) and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding your delete function:
this code line doesnt do what i think you want it to do:

temp = temp->next;

youre trying to change local variable which is  lost anyway when youre out of the function scope

try this fix:
after you initialized temp add this line

```
node *prev = temp
```

in youre while loop the first line should be:

```
prev = temp;
```

and then outside the loop instead:

temp = temp->next;

put this line:

```
prev->next = temp->next;
```